# usrsctp is not built in WebRTC but detected by goolge play store

Tags: webrtc

We compiled WebRTC based on souce code ,using code of milesone m91,and with sctp not built.
1.Our code is based at WebRTC m91
2.**usrsctp** is disalbed and not built by setting these values to false in WebRTC.gni,so that **usrsctp** won't be built.

```
1) rtc_enable_sctp=false
2) rtc_build_usrsctp=false
```

3.build libjingle_peerconnection_so.so by command

```
autoninja -C out/arm libjingle_peerconnection_so
```

4.integrate the compilied libjingle_peerconnection_so.so to App and submit it to google play store

Though **usrsctp** is not built,however,the google play store detects that I'm using a  vulnerable versions of WebRTC use **usrsctp**.
Here is the FAQ from google play store.
[How to fix apps with bad WebRTC versions](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/12577537)

Here is my questions

**Question1：**
How does google store dectect that I'm using a  vulnerable versions of WebRTC use **usrsctp** ?The rules are not clear to me .

- by scanning the symbols in .so ?
- by scanning the meta infos ?

**Question2:**
Is there a way to know the version of WebRTC that libjingle_peerconnection_so.so  is built from ?
In other words,given a specific so file libjingle_peerconnection_so.so ,How can I know that it's built from M91 or M102 ?Is there any meta informations about the version of WebRTC we are used in the compiled products ?

Comment: How did you cross verified that these flags "1) rtc_enable_sctp=false
2) rtc_build_usrsctp=false" are working? When we tried with these flags + we deleted the usrsctp folder from "src/thrid_party/usrsctp", we were expecting no error during compilation. But we got some errors related to usrsctp path.. so it means internally there is still some reference, even though we have set flags to false in args.

Answer (score 2):

WebRTC M012 or higher is required to pass this check on Play, even if usrsctp is removed. While usrsctp is our most pressing concern, many other security issues have been fixed in other components. It is highly recommended that you update to a more recent version, and be prepared to update on an on-going basis in the future if more serious vulnerabilities.

Please don't attempt to circumvent this check in Play, as you will miss important notifications about future security issues, and there is no guarantee that detection will remain the same

Answer (score 0):

I've filed an issue to WebRTC [Issue 14664: usrsctp is not built but detected by goolge play store](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=14664)

Comment: any update or progress on this? we are facing similar issues.